# Экспорт данных из RoomDatabase в Xml-файл

Tags: android, xml, android-room, room

Имеются данные в базе и требуется экспортировать их в Xml-файл. Использую Entity и могу выгрузить любую нужную информацию в List тот же, а как быть дальше? Есть какие-то рабочие методы, чтоб не писать костыль. Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прямого пути Room Entity -> XML нет. Вообще XML считается не совсем подходящим форматом в мобильной разработке, вместо этого используется JSON, поэтому и библиотек для JSON-сериализации много и разных.

Но если мы говорим все-таки о XML, то тут два пути:
1. Ручками, используя `XmlSerializer`. Пример кода: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5933710/5479247
2. Сторонние библиотеки. Навскидку `Jackson` и `Simple`.
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization
http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#start

В обоих случаях нужно забыть о Room Entity и сериализовать данные как обычные POJO.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ и совет. Требуется именно XML-файл для дальнейшей загрузки его в программу.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно получить файл БД, открыть его в Sqlite Browser: https://sqlitebrowser.org (Free) и экспортировать в CSV/JSON/SQL. К сожалению, XML там нет, но можно JSON легко конвертировать в XML (например, http://convertjson.com/json-to-xml.htm)

Comment: Я бы хотел это как-то программно описать, но спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Есть ощущение, что программно (из андроид приложения) выгрузить тоже выполнимая задача, только надо будет написать код, который пробежится по всем таблицам, всем строкам и подготовит xml файл